# Playing video in website using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using php codeigniter. I want to store youtube links of movie trailers in my database and when the user clicks on a thumbnail it should start playing in the website. Pleaseee someone give me idea how to implement this. Thanks in advance ...

Comment: [Here](http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/codeigniter-from-scratch/) is all you need, be quick because this question is going to be closed.

Comment: Codeigniter has no build in video player. Step 1: Try to load a video in html. I would say use HTML 5 video player. Step 2: See how you can connect to your database and get information from it(For example the youtube links). Step 3: Combine the two steps so that it has a video player for every link in the database. Now you will get an nice overview if everything works. step 4: Only create this video player when clicked on a thumbnail. See how far you can come and put some time into this.

Comment: Addintional Note: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask because this question will be closed if you do not edit it. We're not here to create full codes for you.

Comment: do you want to play only you tube related videos or any other videos also

Answer (score 0):

check this integration of jquery and flowplayer it works good [check here](http://www.burconsult.com/tutorials/fancyplayer/index.html)